# Oh-My-ZSH PATH has locations that aren't in .zshrc but are still in path upon echo

Tags: bash, macos, zsh, zshrc

**EDIT:**

I have now deleted the `$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:` portion from line 1 of my `.zshrc` file. So now that line reads as `export PATH=$PATH`. This got rid of the duplicates, but it still doesnt explain **where** Mono and Postgres are being added to the path.

Here is what the path outputs in readable formatting:

```
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

Is there another file that is handling the exportation of these paths?

**ORIGINAL:**

So I really couldn't come up with a very good title, so if anyone has any suggestions please leave them in the comments.

So heres my problem. I just reset my `.zshrc` file to the default template by using the following command.

`cp ~/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template ~/.zshrc`

So here is my file contents for `.zshrc`

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

ZSH_THEME="agnoster"

plugins=(
  git
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

The following files are either completely empty or have everything commented out: `.zprofile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`.

After running the `source .zshrc` command in my terminal followed by the `echo $PATH` command, this is my output.

`/Users/jrobinson/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/jrobinson/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

Let's format this a little better so we can see what's going on:

```
/Users/jrobinson/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/Users/jrobinson/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

As you can see, some things are repeating such as `/usr/local/bin` & `/Users/jrobinson/bin`.

Also I had at one point Postgres installed on my computer, but no longer have it installed. Mono I still have and use, but I have no idea **where** it's being added to my path.

The only thing I'm defining in my path is: `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

So why am I getting these repeat things? I'm assuming it's because of some repeating code somewhere in some file, and I can't pin point where these repeats are occurring so I can delete them and clean up my PATH.

**ALSO** which is really weird, I have Composer installed on my computer as well, and I can use the `composer` command even though I haven't defined Composer in my path with `/.composer/vendor/bin`.

Comment: Since the assignment ends with `$PATH`, you get all the directories that were already in the path, plus the new directories you add at the front. Every time you do `source .zshrc` it adds those two directories again.

Comment: @Barmar I have since deleted the `$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:` from my path, and I'm still getting the Postgres folder path. Though it's not added to the new line, it must be inside of the $PATH variable, but where is this being added so I can get rid of it?

Comment: Probably a system-wide startup file, like `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Here is the contents of that file and it doesn't look like it's adding those folders: https://pastebin.com/fKGSF7sm

Comment: https://scriptingosx.com/2017/05/where-paths-come-from/

Comment: Check `/etc/paths`

Comment: Found it! It was in `/etc/paths.d/`. Each one, both Mono and Postgres had an individual file associated with it. So I just deleted the postgresapp file using the `sudo rm /etc/paths.d/postgresapp` command and restarted terminal. It worked. :P

Comment: Whoever puts up an answer first gets the points.

Comment: @J. Robinson, Please post answers as Answers, not as updates to the Question. (It's perfectly fine to answer your own question!) The text you wrote can be foind [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57719054/3).

Comment: This question really belongs more in [apple.se] or [unix.se]. It's about how MacOS sets the default PATH, not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path_helper` is a helper for constructing `PATH` environment variable. It's macOS exclusive.

> `man path_helper`
>
> Files in these directories should contain one path element per line.
>
> Prior to reading these directories, default `PATH` and `MANPATH` values are
>   obtained from the files `/etc/paths` and `/etc/manpaths` respectively.

A GUI app could put files into these paths. When a shell starts up, values within will be added into `PATH`, or `MANPATH` by `path_helper`. The whole point seems to be *avoiding polluting `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` by creating symlink into them*.

For bash, `path_helper` is called in `/etc/profile` on shell startup. For zsh, `path_helper` is called in `/etc/zprofile`.

Content of `/etc/profile`:

```sh
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

> path_helper -s
>
> -s      Generate Bourne shell commands on stdout.  This is the default if
>   SHELL does not end with "csh".

References

- `man path_helper`

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh ubuntu 20.04 install and arranging my .zshrc file, I was seeing locations in my $path even after commenting out them in .zshrc file. Further to my surprise, those were showing in bash $path as well where none were declared there (check DJANGO_HOME in image below). Used source command several times after each change with no result.

It wasted precious 10 mins of time. Then figured things were fine on a new terminal window. So killing the previous terminal and moving to a new one solved it.

[image]